# Is it with CSS possible to target the first img in each line?

Tags: css, css-float, css-selectors

Is it with CSS possible to target the first img in each line. The img element has the following properties:

```
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
```

I would like to set margin-left to 0 on the first img in each line.

Note that the first img in each line will change when the browser window is maximized and minimized

Is it possible?

Comment: What is a "line"? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Need more context, is the image in any wrapper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing margin on inline-block element after wrapping lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977631/removing-margin-on-inline-block-element-after-wrapping-lines)

Comment: Do your images have the same fixed width? If yes, it is possible using just CSS, even if they all are in the same container. **EDIT** Alright, I read the question again, it's a lot easier than I first thought and very much doable with different sizes of images: put the image container in a wrapper and set the `margin-left` on the container to be `-20px`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used the approach of putting a negative left margin on a img-container. I had also considered this approach but always thought it was a hack. [But it seems to be valid CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just give each of the images a left margin of 20px, and the container they're in a left margin of -20px.

```
.container {margin-left:-20px}
.container img {margin-left:20px; float:left}
```

That way, every img that is on the left side of the container will have an effective margin of 0.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw6fC/3/)

Comment: by doing this we are actually altering whole layout, and dragging it -20px left of the browser window. (Sorry didn't like the approach)

Comment: @wakqasahmed: You can vote however you like, but downvoting a competing answer simply because you "didn't like" it seems rather unreasonable, no?

Comment: You can add a new container so the layout is not changed; instead of `<div class="mylayout"><img1><img2></div>` write `<div class="mylayout"><div class="container"><img1><img2></div></div>`. Nothing will be dragged to the left because the images have a margin-correction.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used the approach of putting a negative left margin on a img-container. I had also considered this approach but always thought it was a hack. But it seems to be valid CSS http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

If the images are not in a div per row, then you have to use JavaScript. I tried doing this with jQuery, it works fine except one problem. I am not getting correct value for `imgPerLine`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/bDWzx/)

#### EDIT

change `var imgWidth = $img.eq(0).outerWidth();` to `var imgWidth = $img.eq(0).outerWidth(true);` and it works a bit better.

---

**jQuery**

```
var $img = $('img');
var imgWidth = $img.eq(0).outerWidth();
var totalImgs = $img.length;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var imgPerLine = Math.floor(windowWidth/imgWidth);
    console.log('imgPerLine:'+imgPerLine);

    $img.each(function () {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '10px');
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < totalImgs - 1; i++) {
        if (i % (imgPerLine) === 0) {
            $img.eq(i).css('margin-left', '0px');
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://goo.gl/UEZSH"> * 8
```

Comment: Hey Sourabh: Thanks for help. I used the CSS approach of putting a negative left margin on a img-container.