# How to control gap between inline-block div elements, such that the gap can be allowed to clip behind the viewport?

Tags: css, html

For example, if we use `display: inline-block` and `margin-right: 20px` to style two `div` elements, the second `div` element prematurely jumps to the next line when the window frame is resized to hit its right margin.

Is there a simple way to get around this problem?

Comment: Although not quite a duplicate, this is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977631/removing-margin-on-inline-block-element-after-wrapping-lines/16978305#16978305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-right: -20px` to the container

Comment: Thanks, I added this to the two divs' container (in this case the body element) and it worked. However, now the bottom left-to-right scrollbar appears as an unwanted side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't perfectly clear, but if Eric's answer doesn't tell you what you need to know, then this might be your issue:

When you set elements to inline-block, any whitespace between them (including newlines) in the source affects the spacing. It's subtle and very frustrating until you realize that's what's happening.

You have two possible solutions.

1) Put everything on one line with no spacing between them in the source code. This is usually not ideal because it's much less readable.

2) Use HTML comments to cause the browser to ignore the space between them. It's not ideal because you have to change the HTML, rather than use some CSS trick, but it works.

For example, if you were making the li elements inline-block, you would do this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li><!--
 --><li>Item 2</li><!--
 --><li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```